# Change aggregate functions to output NULL when a element is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, null, sql-server-2012

Every question I search for about the warning

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Typically people want to treat the NULL values as 0. I want the opposite, how do I modify the following stored procedure to make it return NULL instead of 1?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProcedure 
AS
BEGIN
select cast(null as int) as foo into #tmp

insert into #tmp values (1)

select sum(foo) from #tmp
END
GO
```

I thought it would be `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` (I tried before the declaration, within the procedure itself, and before executing the procedure in my test query) but that did not appear to change the behavior of `SUM(`.

Comment: so you want aggregate functions to return null if any element of the collection is null?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sum()` function automatically ignores `NULL`.  To do what you want, you need an explicit checK:

```
select (case when count(foo) = count(*) then sum(foo) end)
from #tmp;
```

If you want to be explicit, you could add `else NULL` to the `case` statement.

The logic behind this is that `count(foo)` counts the number of non-NULL values in `foo`.  If this is equal to all the rows, then all the values are non-NULL.  You could use the more verbose:

```
select (case when sum(case when foo is null then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then sum(foo)
        end)
```

And, I want to point out that the title is quite misleading.  `1 + NULL = NULL`.  The issue is with the aggregation functions, not the arithmetic operators.

Comment: Would that cause a large performance penalty on large tables due to counting twice?

Comment: Would an `EXISTS` be faster?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain . . . You probably won't notice the difference in performance.  Most of the time of the query will be spent looping through the data pages and fetching them from disk.  A `count()` should be minor overhead in comparison with that effort.

Comment: @DStanley . . . I doubt it.  The query has to do an aggregation anyway, so adding a join (which an `exists` implicitly does) doesn't seem like it will speed it up.  Of course, the OP can try and I might be wrong, but that's my intuition.

Comment: Depends. If `foo` is indexed it could determine that a `NULL` exists quickly and thus avoid the whole scan though.

Comment: Even if there is a scan I wonder if `EXISTS` will stop at the first match (like && does in C#).  I would hope so :)

Comment: @DStanley - It will but if no `NULL` exists you end up scanning the whole thing twice.

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a null value with `EXISTS` may be the fastest:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM tmp WHERE foo IS NULL)
        THEN NULL
        ELSE (SELECT sum(foo) from tmp)
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Just say

```
select case sign(sum(case when foo is null then 1 else 0 end))
       when 1 then null
       else        sum(foo)
       end
 from some_table
 ...
 group by
 ...
```

That's about all you need.